# Chain whereHas to traverse through a self-referencing model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Using Laravel 5.4....

Imagine I have the following models:

**App\Location**

This has a self referencing hierarchy, and has the following data

```
UK
  |---North West
  |             |----Liverpool
  |             |----Manchester
  |---North East
                |----Newcastle
                |----Sunderland
```

In this model I have a self relation

```
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Location', 'location_id');
}
```

and a recursive relation...

```
public function parentRecursive()
{
   return $this->parent()->with('parentRecursive');
}
```

**App\Shop**

The shop model has a 'location' relation.

```
public function location()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Location', 'location_id');
}
```

What I want to do is to get all of the shops within a category. So if I have a shop called "ACME" that is related to "Liverpool", I can easily get it by sending the ID for "Liverpool" (as $value) in the following condition....

```
->whereHas('location', function($q) use ($value) {
        $q->where('id', $value);
})
```

But technically, this shop is also in "North West" and in "UK".

So if I send the ID for the UK Location to that query, it will not return the ACME shop as it is not directly related to North West or UK ID.

I can get it working by sending the UK id ($value) to this...

```
$this->builder->whereHas('location', function($q) use ($value) {
    $q->where('id', $value);
})->orWhereHas('location.parent', function($q) use ($value) {
        $q->where('id', $value);
})->orWhereHas('location.parent.parent', function($q) use ($value) {
        $q->where('id', $value);
});
```

So is there a better way to write the above which is ugly and would only work for a finite number of 'jumps' in the relation tree? I need it to traverse all of the locations until it reaches the top of the tree.

Comment: It's not an answer to your question exactly, but if you're storing several layers of hierarchical data, I would recommend storing it in a [nested set](https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. My solution is not that elegant, but it works without having to use a nested set model:

First, (if you haven't done yet) you may need to create an inverse of your existing recursive relation:

```
public function children() {
  return $this->hasMany('App\Location', 'location_id');
}

public function childrenRecursive() {
  return $this->children()->with('childrenRecursive');
}
```

Next, you need to create a recursive function to get the max **depth**

```
public function getDepth($location) {
  $depth = 0;
  foreach ($location->children as $child) {
    $d = $this->getDepth($child);
    if ($d > $depth) {
      $depth = $d;
    }
  }
  return 1 + $depth;
}
```

Then, you can use the **depth** to chain your query with multiple `orWhereHas` clause

```
$whereHas = 'location';
$query = Shop::whereHas($whereHas, function ($q) use ($value) {
  $q->where('id', $value);
});

for ($d = 1; $depth > $d; $d++) {
  $whereHas = $whereHas . '.parent';
  $query->orWhereHas($whereHas, function ($q) use ($value) {
    $q->where('id', $value);
  });
}
```